# simple php regex with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this string:

```
$string = '<div class="displayEmbededImage" sourcefile="http://site.com/images/myImage.jpg" style="width:200px;"><p>Some text goes here</p></div>';
```

I need a regex that will will select the content of sourcefile and return it like this:

```
$parern = '/<div(.*)sourcefile="([^"]+)"(.*)>(.*)<\/div>/s';
preg_replace($pattern, '<img src="$1">', $string);
```

That's what I have so far, but not getting it quite right yet

Comment: Have you considered using `DOMDocument`?

Answer (score 4):

You do **NOT** use regex on html. Don't even try. Use DOM instead:

```
$d = new DOMdocument();
$d->loadHTML('... your html here ...');
$xp = new DOMXpath($d);
$res = $xp->query('//div[@class="displayEmbededImage"]');
$source = $res->item(0)->getAttribute('sourcefile');
```

Comment: There's a syntax error in the code example (missing square bracket), try `//div[@class="displayEmbededImage"]` as the XPath query.

Comment: Also, `'sourceFile'` should be `'sourcefile'`, and `getAttr` should be `getAttribute`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your variable name, and you are not using the right placeholder:

```
echo preg_replace($parern, '<img src="$2">', $string);
```